# Aliens In Black?

Tags: aliens, men-in-black

**Are there any aliens that actively participate in field work in the *Men In Black* movies?**

I know that there are aliens that work at the organization - that is shoved down our throats - but are there any aliens that are active field agents like K or J, or are all of the agents humans only?

Comment: Me: \**has existential crisis\** Aren't we *all* aliens?

Comment: @Mooz If were all aliens... where would our native land/place-of-origin be?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Yes;** there are or have been "alien" members of the [Men in Black](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Agents), namely:

## Frank the Pug

Our old mate [**Frank the Pug**](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_the_Pug) is actually [Remoolian](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Remoolian)

[image: Image capture of "Frank the Pug" from the Men in Black series]
<sup>[img src](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/men-in-black/images/2/2c/Frank1.png/revision/latest?cb=20110504052735)</sup>

## Agent X

[**Agent X**](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Agent_X) or **Chief X**, is an agent featured in the animated series, *[The Men in Black Series](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Men_in_Black:_The_Series)*, although Agent X' home planet is not listed, he is from the G-Dan Galaxy and clearly doesn't look "hooman" (although he wears a human disguise when out in the field.

[image: Image capture of "Agent X" from the Men in Black animated series]
<sup>[img src](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/men-in-black/images/5/58/Agent_x.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140625014620)</sup>

## Alpha

Although this one is a little bit "iffey", the character [**Alpha**](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Alpha) (F.K.A Agent A) is the former chief of the MiB (Agent "Zed" Z's predecessor). Although originally human, he was exiled, and returned after altering his body and adding alien parts to it which he forcibly collected, making him look, *alien*.

[image: Image capture of the character "Alpha" from the Men in Black series.]
<sup>[img src](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/men-in-black/images/7/7b/Alpha_Alien.PNG/revision/latest?cb=20110527140850)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer with pictures as proof.

Comment: @Imperator You're welcome, glad to help, also, I love pictures :)